# button in form becomes longer in html5 mode

Tags: css, html

This looks good,but in htmtl 5 mode,the search button may get longer.
I use chrome 56 and win 10.

I really can't understand the reason.

The origin code:

```css
body {
    font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;}
 
h1 {
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:8px;
}
 
/* 链接 */
a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#1c00ff;
}
 
a:hover {
    color:#5f00e4;
}
fieldset.search {
    padding: 0px;
    border: none;
    width: 232px;
    background:#e0e0e0;
}
 
fieldset.search:hover {
    background: #a8a8a8;
}
.search input, .search button {
    border: none;
    float: left;
}
.search input.box {
    height: 28px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    background: #e0e0e0;
    margin: 1px;
}
.search input.box:focus {
    background: #e8e8e8 ;
    outline: none;
}
.search button.btn {
    border: none;
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: url(http://sandbox.runjs.cn/uploads/rs/339/livk7pl5/search_blue.png) no-repeat top right;
}
.search button.btn:hover {
    background: url(http://sandbox.runjs.cn/uploads/rs/339/livk7pl5/search_black.png) no-repeat bottom right;
}
 
/* 文章样式 */
.article {
 
}
```

```html
<html>
  
<head>
<title>realize search bar</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

</head>
<body>
<div>
<h2>search bar</h2>
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="http://blog.iliyang.cn/">
    <fieldset class="search">
         <input type="text" class="box" name="s" id="s" class="inputText" placeholder="Valentine’s Day" x-webkit-speech>
          <button class="btn" title="SEARCH"> </button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
<article class="article">
</article>
</body>
</html>
```

The pic[image]

My code,just change the first line to html5:

```css
body {
    font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;}
 
h1 {
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:8px;
}
 
/* 链接 */
a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#1c00ff;
}
 
a:hover {
    color:#5f00e4;
}
fieldset.search {
    padding: 0px;
    border: none;
    width: 232px;
    background:#e0e0e0;
}
 
fieldset.search:hover {
    background: #a8a8a8;
}
.search input, .search button {
    border: none;
    float: left;
}
.search input.box {
    height: 28px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    background: #e0e0e0;
    margin: 1px;
}
.search input.box:focus {
    background: #e8e8e8 ;
    outline: none;
}
.search button.btn {
    border: none;
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: url(http://sandbox.runjs.cn/uploads/rs/339/livk7pl5/search_blue.png) no-repeat top right;
}
.search button.btn:hover {
    background: url(http://sandbox.runjs.cn/uploads/rs/339/livk7pl5/search_black.png) no-repeat bottom right;
}
 
/* 文章样式 */
.article {
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  
<head>
<title>realize search bar</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

</head>
<body>
<div>
<h2>search bar</h2>
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="http://blog.iliyang.cn/">
    <fieldset class="search">
         <input type="text" class="box" name="s" id="s" class="inputText" placeholder="Valentine’s Day" x-webkit-speech>
          <button class="btn" title="SEARCH"> </button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
<article class="article">
</article>
</body>
</html>
```

The pic
[image]

Is there any help please？

Comment: Looks identical to me, I also have Chrome 56

Comment: It doesn't look any different to me. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have ommited "px" in `.search input.box {width: 200px;}`

But I don't know if it solves your problem, because both fields are looking same to me.

Comment: Yeah，it's it.How careless I am.Thank you.